# decimator circuit using dflipflops

Tags: pll, digital-filter

[image]

I am studying about DPLL. There are questions among CDR papers written by the same researchers.

1. Is the symbol likes step symbol after Adder a quantizer?
2. The output of Decimator by factor 2 is -1,0,+1 but eventually enters the input of the next Decimator, and what does -1 mean in a this circuit consisted of dffs?

Comment: Could it be a multi-level phase quantizer? What is the oversampling ratio in the system? Please include more details. {-1,0,+1} could mean {lag, sync, lead} or something similar.

Comment: 1. The input of first decimator stage = output of BangBang Phase detector
2. outputs of decimator are 2-bit
3. Summing 2 bit
4. something likes a step symbol system
5. final output = -1,0,1
6. Again 1~5 to the next Decimator.
Anyway the decimator is consisted of DFF, and input of DFF must be 0 or 1 isnt it? 

Im very not good at english writting Im sorry about that.
Anyway Thank you very much.